# Is there a lightweight open-source alternative to IIS Media Services?

Tags: iis, open-source, video-streaming, audio-streaming

Is there an open-source streaming media framework similar to [IIS Media Services](http://www.iis.net/media)?

I'm building an application to serve time-synced audio and HD video (real-time and playback) with DVR functionality. IIS Media Services looks promising, but I really need something lightweight that I can use for rapid development (preferably using C#). As an analogy, I've shunned WCF in favor of [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) because it is quick-to-develop, and It Just Works.

What open source software do you guys recommend for streaming audio/video over the web? Or, is IIS Media Services relatively easy to dev against? What's the best way to learn IIS Media Services? That site is pretty weak on dev links.

A bit more information: I'm using [Lightstreamer](http://www.lightstreamer.com/) to broadcast dynamic text to ~500 clients. Now I need to add audio and video support (with DVR playback.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently [ffServer](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html) is the only viable open source competitor to IIS Media Services.